# When running a HTTP server using Tornado with content generated using Ember cannot refresh page

Tags: ember.js, tornado

Note: I am new to Tornado.

To recreate my problem I have the following Python file:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.render("dist/index.html")

def start_server():
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', IndexHandler),
        (r'/assets/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "dist/assets"}),
    ])

    ioLoopInstance = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, io_loop=ioLoopInstance)
    http_server.listen(34567)
    ioLoopInstance.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
```

I then have an Ember project that has two routes (/route1 and /route2) with one button on each which just transitions to the other route, and an application route that transitions to route1 in beforeModel. I copy the dist directory generated by Ember to the directory which contains the Python file above. When I run the Python file and navigate to localhost:34567 this automatically transitions to localhost:34567/route1, I can then press the buttons to navigate between pages fine. However, when I refresh the page or enter localhost:34567/route1 in the address bar I get a "404: Not Found" page. What am I missing from my Tornado setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember (as the most of its competitors) has its own **client-based** router, that uses [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (or/and hash routes). Ember, unless you do, does not make any request to the backend.

The solution is simple, in Tornado use the `IndexHandler` for all paths you expect. The common way is to handle all paths, but assets. Example:

```
# note 1: '.*' match all
# note 2: Tornado router matches paths in the order,
#         so match all should be the last
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/assets/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "dist/assets"}),
    (r'/.*', IndexHandler),
])
```